# Get parents and children given a segment in a recursion SQL

Tags: sql-server, recursion, parent-child, nodes, common-table-expression

Given an ID at the beginning or middle or end, I want to look up for all the rows that are linked between them.

With this I found the child elements recursively

```
declare @T table(
  Id int primary key,
  Name nvarchar(255) not null,
  ParentId int)

insert into @T values
(1,   'A',    NULL),
(2,   'B',    1),
(3,   'C',    2),
(4,   'D',    NULL),
(5,   'E',    1)

declare @Id int = 2

;with cte as
(  
  select T.*
  from @T as T
  where T.Id = @Id
  union all
  select T.*
  from @T as T
    inner join cte as C
      on T.ParentId = C.Id
)
select *
from cte
```

If @Id is equals 2, I will get 2 and 3. But I want to retrieve the parent too, in this case 1.

I want to get this:

If id = 1

```
1 A NULL
2 B 1
3 C 2
5 E 1
```

If id = 2

```
1 A NULL
2 B 1
3 C 2
5 E 1
```

If id = 3

```
1 A NULL
2 B 1
3 C 2
5 E 1
```

If id = 4

```
4 D NULL
```

IF id = 5

```
1 A NULL
2 B 1
3 C 2
5 E 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you edit your question and add the desired output ?

Comment: Why for id=1 we should not get '5 E 1' record?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!  I've got you:

I created a separate family for testing.

The first thing you need to do is create a query to find the oldest ancestor of your chosen ID.  That is the first CTE below.  Then you designate that, I called it `@Eve` and find Eve, all children of Eve.

[Here is the example](http://rextester.com/XEGMU60641) you can play around with

```
  create table UserType (
  Id int,
   name nvarchar(255),
  parentid int)

insert into UserType values
(1,  'A',    NULL),
(2,  'B',  1),
(3,  'C',   2),
(4,  'D',    NULL),
(5,  'E',   1),
(6,  'F',   NULL),
(7,  'G',      6),
(8,  'H',     7);

DECLARE @eve BIGINT;  --ancestor
DECLARE @id BIGINT;
SET @id = 8;  --This is where you choose

WITH tblParent AS  --CTE for oldest ancestor
(
    SELECT *
        FROM UserType WHERE Id = @id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserType.*
        FROM UserType  JOIN tblParent  ON UserType.Id = tblParent.ParentId
)
select
@eve = (select top 1 id from tblParent order by id);

WITH tblChild AS  --CTE for all @eve and all children
(
    SELECT *
        FROM UserType WHERE id = @eve
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserType.* FROM UserType  JOIN tblChild  ON UserType.ParentId = tblChild.Id
)
SELECT * FROM tblChild
order by id


OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

[Props to CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child) which was quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question to show my desired output. The query should find all the links between them. Your code won't work if I change the ID = 3 or 5

Comment: @MaximusDecimus thanks for commenting, quick question : you want the parent and all descendants of the parent of your declared ID??  Like for example Children of 5 is null and Parent of 5 is 1.  But you want all Children (2) and GrandChildren (3) of 1?

Comment: All the linked rows by parentid. Grandparents ,parents, children an so on. All related rows. I will have a maximum of 4 levels but if I look up for grandchild I will be able to find all the children and parents and grand parents and all related to these grand parents.

Comment: @MaximusDecimus ok got it, all related rows, poor lonely Id = 4 :''(

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
declare  @tbl table( --test table var
Id int,
name nvarchar(255),
parentid int)

insert into @tbl values -- test data
(1,  'A',    NULL),
(2,  'B',  1),
(3,  'C',   2),
(4,  'D',    NULL),
(5,  'E',   1),
(6,  'F',   NULL),
(7,  'G',      6),
(8,  'H',     7);

declare @id int = 7

;with parents as (
select id,name,parentid, 0 lvl
from @tbl 
where id=@id
union all
select t.id,t.name,t.parentid,  lvl-1
from @tbl t
inner join parents p on t.Id=p.parentid --up the tree
)
,children as (
select id,name,parentid, 0 lvl
from @tbl 
where id=@id --select single record
union all
select t.id,t.name,t.parentid,  lvl+1
from @tbl t
inner join children c on c.Id=t.parentid -- down the tree
)
select * from parents
union --combine results
select * from children
order by lvl
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you valuable answer. I could not get the number 5 when I search for 2 or 3. Just at 1 or 5 directly. But your code served as a model for another scenario when I want to get all the linked rows for a branch but not cousins! Thank you so much.